# Render a 1/2 true & 1/2 false bool function by another function returning bool probabilistically

Tags: probability

**Problem**

Given a bool function g() which returns true with 1/4 and false with 3/4,
use that function to render another bool function f() which returns true with 1/2 and false with 1/2.

I saw this question on an interview review website, and there are no answers to it.

I tried to solve it but failed after several hours.

I appreciate any suggestions.

**Possible Answer**

I wrote some python code by simplifying the answer from @Zubin Mukerjee

```
def f():
    while True:
        x = g()
        y = g()
        if x != y:
            return x
```

Comment: Could you clarify the question? I am not sure what you're asking

Comment: @MathUser_NotPrime I've edited it.

Comment: call the original function twice and return true only if you get true both times sort of $g=f \land f$

Comment: @Vasya I think it's the other way around - you have g, how can you use it to return f?

Comment: @ConMan Yes it's the other way around. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: OK, the original question was different. Nevertheless, the same technique will work with different operator $f=g \oplus g$

Comment: I'm not sure if I am reading the question correctly, but I've posted an answer. Let me know if it isn't what was asked. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've written some Java code as a sample solution to your problem.

The function `threefourthspotato` below is true with probability $1/4$, and false with probability $3/4$.

I have used it to construct a function `halfpotato` that is true with probability $1/2$, and false with probability $1/2$.

---

```
public static boolean threefourthspotato() {
    return (Math.random() > 0.75);
}
```

---

In Java, `Math.random()` is a double chosen between $0$ and $1$. This means that the function `threefourthspotato` will return true with probability $1/4$, and false with probability $3/4$.

How I have constructed `threefourthspotato` here is irrelevant, the only fact that is relevant to `halfpotato` working as intended is that `threefourthspotato` returns true with probability $1/4$.

---

```
public static boolean halfpotato() {
    int x=0;
    boolean y = false;   // this will eventually be true with probability 1/2
    while (x < 1) {      // x is a dummy variable for the loop
        y = threefourthspotato();
        boolean z = threefourthspotato();
        if (y ^ z) {     // if y XOR z is true
            x = 1;       // then end the loop
        }
    }
    return y;
}
```

---

**This method is analogous to a common method used for [simulating a fair coin using multiple flips of a biased coin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_coin#Fair_results_from_a_biased_coin).**

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I checked the reference, and I think the answer can  be simplified. I added the code snippet to my question, could you check if they do the same thing?